# deploying gatsby (v2) to netlify errors

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I'm having some issues deploying to netlify. These are the errors I receive:

`Error: ./src/pages/index.js
12:55:30 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Featured' in '/opt/build  /repo/src/pages'
12:55:30 PM:   resolve '../components/Featured' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
12:55:30 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/p  ages)
12:55:30 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`

For some reason it can't find the components. Building locally works fine.

I used gatsby-starter w styled-components.

things I tried:
I had some local building errors regarding the window undefined. I fixed these by conditionally including them as [the manual proposes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

After applying this, I started receiving console logs from ‘workbox’.

(btw this is my first time trying to deploy to netlify)
also the error `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration` keeps repeating in the logs

[here's a link to the full log](https://pastebin.com/VZDuTrEm) I get from netlify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors are due to webpack not being able to resolve your relative paths. Make sure to use the correct case.

```
import Hero from '../components/hero'
import Introduce from '../components/introduce'
import HelpMeHelpYou from '../components/helpmehelpyou'
import Featured from '../components/featured'
import Testimonials from '../components/testimonials'
import Projects from '../components/projects'
import Gallery from '../components/gallery'
import Outroduce from '../components/outroduce'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run below command and then push the code to Github repository.

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```